# JS Позиции всех пробелов в тексте, замена?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать что б один из пробелов (случайным образом) между словами заменялся на слово " word " (ну или любое другое из массива) . Иначе говоря, я хочу что б в текст после загрузки страници в случайное место добавлялось слово. На этом примере

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var allSpaces = [];

  var allText = $(".block").text();
  var findAllSpaces = [],
    start = 0,
    ind;
  while (ind = allText.indexOf(' ', start), ind != -1) {
    findAllSpaces.push(ind);
    start = ind + 1;
  }
  console.log("Spaces = " + findAllSpaces);

  var lengthAllSpaces = findAllSpaces.length;
  var word = " WORD ";

  var randomPlaceForWord = Number.parseInt(Math.random() * lengthAllSpaces, 10);
  alert(" randomPlaceForWord =" + findAllSpaces[randomPlaceForWord]);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum deleniti, eius assumenda culpa aut quas voluptatibus recusandae nihil in expedita!</div>
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, pariatur.</div>
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure amet quae vitae provident maiores sequi, veniam assumenda quis expedita optio dolor nobis nesciunt illo error rerum, reiciendis in cumque necessitatibus.</div>
```

*Тут я нашел все индексы пробелов в тексте, но вот как проводить подмену пока не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделаем спец-функцию для этого:

```
String.prototype.insert = function(idx, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx);
};
```

И используем ее:

```
var result = allText.insert(findAllSpaces[randomPlaceForWord], " word ");
```